# Javascript Capitalize the First Name in a Form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make the following work `onChange` when a user leaves the first name field.  I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

```
function changeCase()  //Change first letter to uppercase and the rest to lowercase
{
  var fName = document.getElementById('firstName');
  var properCaseString = fName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + fName.substring(1,fName.length);
  document.getElementById('firstName').value = properCaseString;
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get? We'll also need to see your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fName is an element, not a string:

```
var fName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
```

is probably what you actually wanted to get.

Answer (score 1):

You can (sort of) do this with CSS.

```
//won't change a name that is all caps
<style>
#firstName{
  text-transform:capitalize;
}
</style>
```

or if there is only 1 word, so if they entered "`mary jane`" it would be "`Mary jane`"

```
<style>
#firstName{ text-transform: lowercase; }
#firstName:first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
</style>
```